# SQL Server Express 2008 Installation failure due to NET framework

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server

I am trying to install microsoft sql server express 2008 on windows xp which has both net framework 2.0 and 3.5 installed and in the log i find this error. I have no idea how does this happen. I verified HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Net Framework Setup\NDP\2.0.50727\Install value is 0x1

```
01/13/2014 15:45:06.578 ======================================================================
01/13/2014 15:45:06.578 Setup launched
01/13/2014 15:45:06.578 Attempting to determine media source
01/13/2014 15:45:06.578 Media source value not specified on command line argument.
01/13/2014 15:45:06.578 Setup is launched from media directly so default the value to the current folder.
01/13/2014 15:45:06.593 Media source: c:\59da7d719009b7aa270f\
01/13/2014 15:45:06.593 Attempt to determine media layout based on file 'c:\59da7d719009b7aa270f\mediainfo.xml'.
01/13/2014 15:45:07.078 Media layout is detected as: Core
01/13/2014 15:45:07.078 Media LCID is detected as: 1033
01/13/2014 15:45:07.078 Local setup.exe not found, so continuing to run setup.exe from media.
01/13/2014 15:45:07.078 /? or /HELP or /ACTION=HELP specified: false
01/13/2014 15:45:07.078 Help display: false
01/13/2014 15:45:07.078 Checking to see if we need to install .Net version 2.0
01/13/2014 15:45:07.093 Determining the cluster status of the local machine.
01/13/2014 15:45:07.109 The local machine is not configured as a cluster node.
01/13/2014 15:45:07.109 Attempting to find media for .Net version 2.0
01/13/2014 15:45:07.109 .Net version 2.0 needs to be installed from media: c:\59da7d719009b7aa270f\
01/13/2014 15:45:07.109 Error: Unable to find media for .Net version 2.0
01/13/2014 15:45:07.109 .Net version 2.0 installation failed, so setup will close. Error code: 0x84C40007
01/13/2014 15:45:07.109 Setup closed with exit code: 0x84C40007
01/13/2014 15:45:07.109 ======================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the full version of .Net installed or is it just the stripped down client profile?

Comment: Have a butchers at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kbarticle.aspx?id=318785

Comment: well i have the full versions

Comment: is there anything to do with .net 2.0 in c:\59da7d719009b7aa270f\?

Comment: i dont think so because that is just a temporary folder that the installer creates..

Comment: Im really wondering whether .net 2.0 is actually packaged in with your version of SQL. Have you tried redownloading and installing .net? By the way SQL server is an absolute B**** to install, once you have done it a couple of times you get used to it but the setup "wizard" is scraping the barrel of microsoft ineptitude (saying something!)

Comment: @StevenWood this belongs in the comment section and not the answer section.